# Is there a way to model multiple objects using marshmallow sqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I have the following SqlAlchemy configuration (pseudo code for brevity):

```
class A(BaseModel):
   id: column...
   b_id: column...
   b: relationship...

class B(BaseModel):
   id: column...
   name: column...

class C(BaseModel):
   id: column...
   b_id: column...
   b: relationship...
```

I have a Marshmallow SqlAlchemy schema that looks like this:

```
class BSchema(SqlAlchemyAutoSchema):
   class Meta:
      model = B
      include_fk = True

class ASchema(SqlAlchemyAutoSchema):
   class Meta:
      model = A
      include_relationships = False
      include_fk = True
      load_instance = True
   b = Nested(BSchema, many=False)
```

The query that I'm using looks like this:

```
session.query(A, C.id)
   .join(B,A.b_id = B.id)
   .join(C,C.b_id = B.id)
   .all()
```

How can I include `C.id` in my `ASchema` class so I can access it later?